# FCM Notification icon is not being used

Tags: android, user-interface, notifications

I am using `FCM` and I could successfully send push notification to my app. I want to use custom notification icon but it always show white icon. I am running `Lollipop`.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support) it says

> icon  Optional, string    Indicates notification icon. Sets value to
>   myicon for drawable resource myicon.

( I'm not sure what exactly it means ). But here are what I did.

1. I generated icons from [here](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html) . It does have icons with only white text and transparent background. Sample screenshot pic of the icon is [image]
2. I added to res folder [image]
3. I edited my AndroidManifest and added this `android:icon="@drawable/ic_stat_set" in <Application`
4. I tried running the project on the device, the new app icon *ic_stat_set* are being used as app launcher.
5. From the console I send notification and I did receive it but its not the icon I just set.
6. I also tried sending through api. I did received the notification but not the icon that i set.

   `curl -X POST --header "Authorization: key=SERVERKEY" --Header "Content-Type: application/json" https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d "{\"to\":\"REGISTERATION-TOKEN-ID\",\"notification\":{\"body\":\"Yellow\" , \"icon\" : \"ic_stat_set\"} \"priority":\"10"}"`

UPDATE : my drawable icons files are https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5Fi1l7EbQ_BOERUMzNuQy1OWXM

Do I have to put something in those custom data files in the console ? My icon ?  What I am missing ?

Thanks

Comment: you will required **silhouette** for loliipop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be your icon size for the status bar that is off

Take a look here.

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html

Your app icon should be different than your notification icon.

The icon param in the notification is for the status bar.

The icon param in the Manifest is for the app icon(Shortcut)

I recommend this [sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5Fi1l7EbQ_BOERUMzNuQy1OWXM  Here is the res folder icon files. What you think ?

Comment: @cjmling You need 2 icon, one for the launcher, and one for the notification. They are different size. Fix this and read what I've sent you, it should work. Works perfectly fine for me with these changes.

Comment: Thanks its working now.. I actually read the article but could not find what were wrong. Now i just copied drawable icons/folder from the sample app and test. Working great. :)  .. may be there were problems in the icons sizes or its requirement which i could not figure out what it was.

Answer (score 0):

`Lollipop` version use icon without background `png` image.

```
  NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setContentText(message).setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, builder.build());


private int getNotificationIcon() {
    boolean useWhiteIcon = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
    return useWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.logo : R.drawable.ic_launcher;
}
```

Comment: The screenshot of the icon i provided above does clearly tell that its a png with no background , isn't it ?

Comment: He is using FCM and Lollipop, with no data field. This code will never be executed. Its the system that will display the notification.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **silhouette icon** . you have to create silhouette icon of your icon(i.e  notification icon ) . White background problem will resolve by this.
 Its worked for me . Please try it .

Comment: and you should also study this link:->  https://blog.clevertap.com/fixing-notification-icon-for-android-lollipop-and-above/

Comment: I did have transparent icon same as whats mentioned in the blog link u supplied. Issue still there. :S

Comment: have to create silhouette icon of notification icon(whatever you what) ? you should try . it may  work. it is worked for me.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5Fi1l7EbQ_BOERUMzNuQy1OWXM Here is the files of the icon. Are they silhouette ?

Comment: try this icon once ->https://www.google.co.in/search?q=silhouette+icon&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=667&tbm=isch&imgil=zsWC_-e7sF4a3M%253A%253BkR1zZofLkAr0uM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.freepik.com%25252Ffree-icon%25252Fmale-user-silhouette_710068.htm&source=iu&pf=m&fir=zsWC_-e7sF4a3M%253A%252CkR1zZofLkAr0uM%252C_&usg=__rad0cvVMHgT_rQ1zoJIZwXGU31I%3D&dpr=1&ved=0ahUKEwid8qqL6e7OAhVJPo8KHROQDvwQyjcIPQ&ei=c3bIV93sGcn8vASToLrgDw#imgrc=zsWC_-e7sF4a3M%3A.

Answer (score 0):

By default android API after Lolipop's status bar's icon tint color is white, you need to set icon for upper version and older version. Without hack you can try this:

```
  int icon = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP ? R.drawable.your_logo_for_Kitkat : R.mipmap.your_logo_for_Lolipop_and_uper_version;
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("shortDescription"))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setColor(Color.RED)
                .setStyle(notiStyle)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: He is using FCM and Lollipop, with no data field. This code will never be executed. Its the system that will display the notification.

Comment: And also system to set icon or logo for his notification!!